# Wrong tick labels alignment on baseline

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, vertical-alignment, ticks

Here is an example replicating a problem I faced using the `xticklabels from table` feature:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xtick={1e-4, .1, .3},
    xticklabels={\num{e-4}, .2, .3},
    ]
    \addplot[only marks] table[x=x, y=y] {
      x y
      -.3 .7
      .2 .1
      .5 .6
      0.4 -0.5
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and a picture of the output:

[image: sample output]

The xticklabels are not properly aligned on their baseline.
I suppose I could correct this by altering the xticklabels properties or maybe by using another way to format the numbers.
What would be the bette way to ensure proper alignment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can fix the `text height` by setting `xticklabel style={text height=2ex}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xtick={1e-4, .1, .3},
    xticklabels={\num{e-4}, 0.2, 0.3},
    xticklabel style={text height=2ex}
    ]
    \addplot[only marks] table[x=x, y=y] {
      x y
      -.3 .7
      .2 .1
      .5 .6
      0.4 -0.5
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a [better answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386584/aligning-axis-tick-labels/386612#386612) — just add style `typeset ticklabels with strut`.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and fastest way that comes to my mind is to add a phantom exponent:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand{\pe}[1]{$#1^{\vphantom{1}}$}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xtick={1e-4, .1, .3},
    xticklabels={\num{e-4}, \pe{0.2}, \pe{0.3}},
    ]
    \addplot[only marks] table[x=x, y=y] {
      x y
      -.3 .7
      .2 .1
      .5 .6
      0.4 -0.5
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```