# Aligning axis tick labels

Tags: pgfplots

Hi I am using a mixed notation labelling system (scientific+non-scientific). Due to this the exponent of the scientific notation is causing certain labels to be misaligned. Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9, every tick label/.append style={font=\normalsize}}    

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
Keff    PCCR
48.49  1000 
38.52  300  
25     100
19     50
7.4    10
0.844  2
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{data.dat}{\2}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title={Some title},
enlarge x limits=-1,
symbolic x coords={1000,300,100,50,10,2},
xlabel={X-axis},
xtick={1000,300,100,50,10,2},
xticklabels={$\mathrm{1\times10^3}$,$\mathrm{3\times10^2}$,$100$,$50$,$10$,$2$},
scaled ticks=true,
ymin=0.5, ymax=50,
ylabel={Y-axis},
]
\addplot  table [x={PCCR}, y={Keff}] {\2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `xticklabel style={text height=2ex},` to the axis options, which will align the labels on their baseline.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is the option `typeset ticklabels with strut` to align the ticklabels. Just add it to the `axis` environment options.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
Keff    PCCR
48.49  1000
38.52  300
25     100
19     50
7.4    10
0.844  2
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.3,
    }
    \pgfplotstableread{data.dat}{\2}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title={Some title},
        ymin=0.5,
        ymax=50,
        ylabel={Y-axis},
        xlabel={X-axis},
        symbolic x coords={1000,300,100,50,10,2},
        xtick=data,
        xticklabels={
            $1 \times 10^3$,
            $3 \times 10^2$,
            $100$,
            $50$,
            $10$,
            $2$%
        },
        typeset ticklabels with strut,  % <-- added
        enlarge x limits=false,         % <-- (renamed to `false' from `1')
    ]
        \addplot table [x={PCCR}, y={Keff}] {\2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]